# 404 htaccess redirect is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat

I am running tomcat on apache we server.
I am putting .htacces in project folder inside tomcat/webapps directory.
I am using following line inside .htaccess for 404 redirection

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404Redirect.html
```

But it is not working. Please let me know the location where i should place .htaccess or if i am doing mistake in redirection code

Comment: 1) It is possible that usage of .htaccess is forbidden by Apache configuration .. or it has to be named differently -- consult your sysadmin or hosting company; 2) What do you mean by "404 redirection" ?

Comment: +1, @LazyOne , yes this was only the reason. But can't select your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1):

i had same problem. I solved it by adding `RewriteEngine on` before `ErrorDocument 404 /404Redirect.html`

please ensure that `404Redirect.html` is in the same directory as the `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

First check if you can use `.htaccess` file! Second your file(`404Redirect.html`) related to your document root NOT `.htacsess`  file!

Comment: I placed 404Redirect.html in web application root only. Even though i had tried with absolute path as well. But it is not working. How can i check whether use of .htaccess is allowed or not?

Comment: @noquery check server config for AllowOverride directive to be All